# Live SDK for windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, onedrive, live-sdk

Hay there, I'm learning the live SDK fro windows phone 8 & I'm using Live SDK 5.5.
I have downloaded the SDK, installed it and referenced it in my project
I also have created a key for my application and I followed the exact code in [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826550.aspx) 
and that's my code: 
XAML

```
    <live:SignInButton ClientId="my ID" x:Name="btnSignin" Scopes="wl.signin wl.basic" Branding="Skydrive" SessionChanged="btnSignin_SessionChanged" Margin="10,0,-10,194" Height="104" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  />
    <TextBlock Height="102" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="26,128,0,0" Name="infoTextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="419" />
</Grid>
```

and that's my C# code

```
    private async void btnSignin_SessionChanged(object sender, LiveConnectSessionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Status == LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected)
        {
            client = new LiveConnectClient(e.Session);
            LiveOperationResult operationResult = await client.GetAsync("me");
            try
            {
                dynamic meResult = operationResult.Result;
                if (meResult.first_name != null &&
                    meResult.last_name != null)
                {
                    infoTextBlock.Text = "Hello " +
                        meResult.first_name + " " +
                        meResult.last_name + "!";
                }
                else
                {
                    infoTextBlock.Text = "Hello, signed-in user!";
                }
            }
            catch (LiveConnectException exception)
            {
                this.infoTextBlock.Text = "Error calling API: " +
                    exception.Message;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            infoTextBlock.Text = "Not signed in.";
        }
    }
```

But the application doesn't show me the login page so that I enter my user name and password for my live account it just loads and then it says " not signed in" in the text box.

Comment: Have you tried adding wl.skydrive to Scopes: `Scopes="wl.signin wl.skydrive wl.basic"`? And also check if you have marked your App as for mobiles (there where you have registered it and obtained ID).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out after checking comments adding `wl.skydrive` to Scopes property solved the issue:

```
<live:SignInButton ClientId="my ID" x:Name="btnSignin" Scopes="wl.signin wl.basic wl.skydrive" 
 Branding="Skydrive" SessionChanged="btnSignin_SessionChanged" Margin="10,0,-10,194"
 Height="104" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
```

More about available scopes you [can read here at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh243646.aspx).

Also your App should me marked as *for mobile devices* at [your account](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/live).